# How do you validate that range doesn't overlap in a list of data?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of data :

```
Id   StartAge     EndAge      Amount 
1           0        2        50
2           2        5        100
3           5        10       150    
4           6        9        160
```

I have to set Amount for various age group.

```
The age group  >0 and <=2 need to pay 50
The age group  >2 and <=5 need to pay 100
The age group  >5 and <=10 need to pay 150
```

But 
`The age group  >6 and <=9` need to pay 160 is an invalid input because `>6 and <=9` already exist on 150 amount range.

I have to validate such kind of invalid input  before inserting my data as a bulk.Once 5-10 range gets inserted anything that is within this range should not be accepted by system. For example: In above list, user should be allowed to insert 10-15 age group but any of the following should be checked as invalid.

1. 6-9
2. 6-11
3. 3-5
4. 5-7

If Invalid Input exists on my list I don't need to insert the list.

Comment: With a stricter set of constraints (notable, no *gaps* allowed *between* ranges) this can be enforced with unique and foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to insert your data to the temporary table first.

```
DECLARE @TempData TABLE
(
    [Id] TINYINT
   ,[StartAge] TINYINT
   ,[EndAge] TINYINT
   ,[Amount] TINYINT 
);    
INSERT INTO @TempData ([Id], [StartAge], [EndAge], [Amount])
VALUES (1, 0, 2, 50)
      ,(2, 2, 5, 100)
      ,(3, 5, 10, 150)
      ,(4, 6, 9, 160);
```

Then, this data will be transferred to your target table using **INSERT INTO... SELECT...** statement.

```
INSERT INTO <your target table>
SELECT * FROM  @TempData s
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM @TempData t
    WHERE 
      t.[Id] < s.[Id] 
      AND s.[StartAge] < t.[EndAge]
      AND s.[EndAge] > t.[StartAge] 
    );
```

I've created a demo [here](http://rextester.com/TULRK88944)

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you did in the not exists block

Comment: What I did is just checking that not exists record which have smaller [Id] and be overlaped range with checking record.

Answer (score 1):

We can use recursive `CTE` to find how records are chained by `end age` and `start age` pairs:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Id] TINYINT
   ,[StartAge] TINYINT
   ,[EndAge] TINYINT
   ,[Amount] TINYINT 
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Id], [StartAge], [EndAge], [Amount])
VALUES (1, 0, 2, 50)
      ,(2, 2, 5, 100)
      ,(3, 5, 10, 150)
      ,(4, 6, 9, 160)
      ,(5, 6, 11, 160)
      ,(6, 3, 5, 160)
      ,(7, 5, 7, 160)
      ,(9, 10, 15, 20)
      ,(8, 7, 15, 20);


WITH PreDataSource AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [StartAge] ORDER BY [id]) as [pos]
    FROM @DataSource
), DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [Id], [StartAge], [EndAge], [Amount], [pos]
    FROM PreDataSource
    WHERE [id] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT R.[Id], R.[StartAge], R.[EndAge], R.[Amount], R.[pos]
    FROM DataSource A
    INNER JOIN PreDataSource R
        ON A.[Id] < R.[Id]
        AND A.[EndAge] = R.[StartAge]
        AND R.[pos] =1

)
SELECT [Id], [StartAge], [EndAge], [Amount]
FROM DataSource;
```

This is giving us, the following output:

[image]

Note, that before this, we are using the following statement to prepare the data:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [StartAge] ORDER BY [id]) as [pos]
FROM @DataSource;
```

The idea is to find records with same start age and to calculated which one is inserted first. Then, in the CTE we are getting only the first.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are bulk inserting the mentioned data into a temp table(#tmp) or table variable (@tmp).

If you are working on sql server 2012 try the below.

```
select * 
from(select *,lag(endage,1,0)over(order by endage) as [col1]
from @tmp)tmp
where startage>=col1 and endage>col1
```

The result of this query should be inserted into your main table.